# Optional parameters for NewDocumentCommand with if cases

Tags: macros, expl3, optional-arguments

I have this command, which I would like to take two optional parameters: `\pubtitle[title][symbol]{custom}`.

Here is the command (MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\definecolor{icons}{HTML}{46A247}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \pubtitle_symbolheading:nn
 {
  \group_begin:
  {\large\textcolor{icons}{#1}\hspace{10pt}\textbf{#2}}
  \group_end:
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\pubtitle}{m}
 {
  \pubtitle_pubtitle:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \pubtitle_pubtitle:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {book}{\pubtitle_symbolheading:nn{\faBook}{Book}}
    {article}{\pubtitle_symbolheading:nn{\faFileText}{Article}}
    % other cases
   }
   {% none of the above
    \PackageError{pubtitle}
     {
      Unsupported ~ entry ~ field ~ '#1' ~ \MessageBreak for bibliography}
     {
      Perhaps ~ you ~ meant ~ '\string\pubtitle{custom}'
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\pubtitle{book}

\pubtitle{article}

\pubtitle{invalidArgument}

\end{document}
```

This returns an error for an "unsupported" mandatory parameter. What I would like is to be able to provide two optional parameters (one for each in the `\pubtitle_symbolheading:nn` command) when the mandatory parameter `custom` is given. The output of MWE is:

[image]

What I want is to **be able to change the bold text and symbol in the output with optional parameters** (but only if `custom` is given as the mandatory parameter).

I would like to be  able to change the title without the symbol, i.e. `\pubtitle[title]{custom}`.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want, tbh. You're showing a command with a single optional argument, in which you separate stuff by a comma, but your code doesn't use any optional argument, and I honestly don't understand what any optional argument should do.

Comment: @Skillmon I edited it to be more clear. I was not aware of how to provide several optional parameters, and assumed it was something like ``\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}``, where the parameters are separated by comma.

Comment: the separation by comma is what's used for key=value or class and package options, but traditionally not optional arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following provides two internally identical solutions with a different document interface. The first, called `\pubtitle` uses two optional arguments followed by a mandatory one. The second, called `\Pubtitle` uses the interface you showed in your question with a single optional argument in which the two things are split by a comma.

Also, the third argument will be normalised by `\str_foldcase:n`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\definecolor{icons}{HTML}{46A247}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn { pubtitle } { extraneous-optional }
  {
    \exp_not:N \pubtitle
    only~ accepts~ optional~ arguments~ if~ you~ use~ `custom'~ as~ a~
    mandatory~ argument.
  }
\msg_new:nnn { pubtitle } { missing-optional }
  {
    \exp_not:N \pubtitle
    requires~ two~ optional~ arguments~ if~ you~ use~ `custom'~ as~ a~
    mandatory~ argument.
  }
\msg_new:nnnn { pubtitle } { unsupported-argument }
  { Unsupported~ entry~ field~ `#1'~ for~ bibliography. }
  { Perhaps~ you~ meant~ `\token_to_str:N \pubtitle[<icon>][<text>]{custom}'. }

% document interfaces
\NewDocumentCommand \pubtitle { o o m }
  { \pubtitle_pubtitle:nne {#1} {#2} { \str_foldcase:n {#3} } }
\NewDocumentCommand \Pubtitle { >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}o m }
  {
    % design decision of ltcmd: unused o-args are not processed by argument
    % processors, so we need to add this processing here
    \IfNoValueTF {#1}
      { \pubtitle_pubtitle:nne {#1} {#1} }
      { \pubtitle_pubtitle:nne #1 }
        { \str_foldcase:n {#2} }
  }

% internal code
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pubtitle_pubtitle:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \str_case:nnTF {#3}
      {
        { book }    { \pubtitle_symbolheading:nn \faBook     { Book } }
        { article } { \pubtitle_symbolheading:nn \faFileText { Article } }
      }
      {
        \bool_lazy_and:nnF
          { \tl_if_novalue_p:n {#1} }
          { \tl_if_novalue_p:n {#2} }
          { \msg_error:nn { pubtitle } { extraneous-optional } }
      }
      {
        \str_if_eq:nnTF {#3} { custom }
          {
            \bool_lazy_or:nnTF
              { \tl_if_novalue_p:n {#1} }
              { \tl_if_novalue_p:n {#2} }
              { \msg_error:nn { pubtitle } { missing-optional } }
              { \pubtitle_symbolheading:nn {#1} {#2} }
          }
          { \msg_error:nnn { pubtitle } { unsupported-argument } {#3} }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \pubtitle_pubtitle:nnn { nne }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pubtitle_symbolheading:nn #1#2
  {
    \group_begin:
      \large
      \textcolor { icons } {#1}
      \skip_horizontal:n { 10pt }
      \textbf {#2}
    \group_end:
  }

% just for tests
\NewDocumentCommand \showtest { v }
  {
    \noindent\texttt{#1}:\\
    \tl_rescan:nn {} {#1}
    \par
    \medskip
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{Interface \texttt{\protect\string\pubtitle}}
\showtest{\pubtitle{book}}
\showtest{\pubtitle{ArTiClE}}
\showtest{\pubtitle[\faBeer][Beer]{custom}} % thanks Ulrich for the beer

% error cases
%\pubtitle{invalidArgument} % throws an error
%\pubtitle[\faBook]{article} % throws an error
%\pubtitle[\faBook]{custom} % throws an error

\section{Interface \texttt{\protect\string\Pubtitle}}
\showtest{\Pubtitle{book}}
\showtest{\Pubtitle{ArTiClE}}
\showtest{\Pubtitle[\faBeer,Beer]{custom}} % thanks Ulrich for the beer

%\Pubtitle{invalidArgument} % throws an error
%\Pubtitle[\faBook]{article} % throws an error
%\Pubtitle[\faBook]{custom} % throws an error
%\Pubtitle[\faBeer,Beer, and more]{custom} % throws an error
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The following uses default values for the title and icon if `custom` was used. If you specify both optional arguments (or in the variant with a comma the variant with a separation) then the first will be the title and the second the icon. If you specify only one optional argument, if that contains only a single token/braced group that will be used as the icon and the title will be the default one. If you only specify one optional argument and it contains more than a single token/group it'll be the title and the default icon is used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\definecolor{icons}{HTML}{46A247}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn { pubtitle } { extraneous-optional }
  {
    \exp_not:N \pubtitle
    only~ accepts~ optional~ arguments~ if~ you~ use~ `custom'~ as~ a~
    mandatory~ argument.
  }
\msg_new:nnnn { pubtitle } { unsupported-argument }
  { Unsupported~ entry~ field~ `#1'~ for~ bibliography. }
  { Perhaps~ you~ meant~ `\token_to_str:N \pubtitle[<icon>][<text>]{custom}'. }

% document interfaces
\NewDocumentCommand \pubtitle { o o m }
  { \pubtitle_pubtitle:nne {#1} {#2} { \str_foldcase:n {#3} } }
\NewDocumentCommand \Pubtitle { >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}o m }
  {
    % design decision of ltcmd: unused o-args are not processed by argument
    % processors, so we need to add this processing here
    \IfNoValueTF {#1}
      { \pubtitle_pubtitle:nne {#1} {#1} }
      { \pubtitle_pubtitle:nne #1 }
        { \str_foldcase:n {#2} }
  }

\tl_new:N \l__pubtitle_default_custom_icon_tl
\tl_new:N \l__pubtitle_default_custom_title_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l__pubtitle_default_custom_icon_tl { \faFileTextO }
\tl_set:Nn \l__pubtitle_default_custom_title_tl { Publication }

% internal code
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pubtitle_pubtitle:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \str_case:nnTF {#3}
      {
        { book }    { \pubtitle_symbolheading:nn \faBook     { Book } }
        { article } { \pubtitle_symbolheading:nn \faFileText { Article } }
      }
      {
        \tl_if_novalue:nF {#1}
          { \msg_error:nn { pubtitle } { extraneous-optional } }
      }
      {
        \str_if_eq:nnTF {#3} { custom }
          {
            \tl_if_novalue:nTF {#2}
              {
                \tl_if_novalue:nTF {#1}
                  {
                    \pubtitle_symbolheading:nn
                      \l__pubtitle_default_custom_icon_tl
                      \l__pubtitle_default_custom_title_tl
                  }
                  {
                    \tl_if_single:nTF {#1}
                      {
                        \pubtitle_symbolheading:nn
                          #1
                          \l__pubtitle_default_custom_title_tl
                      }
                      {
                        \pubtitle_symbolheading:nn
                          \l__pubtitle_default_custom_icon_tl
                          {#1}
                      }
                  }
              }
              { \pubtitle_symbolheading:nn {#2} {#1} }
          }
          { \msg_error:nnn { pubtitle } { unsupported-argument } {#3} }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \pubtitle_pubtitle:nnn { nne }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pubtitle_symbolheading:nn #1#2
  {
    \group_begin:
      \large
      \textcolor { icons } {#1}
      \skip_horizontal:n { 10pt }
      \textbf {#2}
    \group_end:
  }

% just for tests
\NewDocumentCommand \showtest { v }
  {
    \noindent\texttt{#1}:\\
    \tl_rescan:nn {} {#1}
    \par
    \medskip
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{Interface \texttt{\protect\string\pubtitle}}
\showtest{\pubtitle{book}}
\showtest{\pubtitle{ArTiClE}}
\showtest{\pubtitle[Beer][\faBeer]{custom}} % thanks Ulrich for the beer
\showtest{\pubtitle[\faBeer]{custom}}
\showtest{\pubtitle[Beer]{custom}}

% error cases
%\pubtitle{invalidArgument} % throws an error
%\pubtitle[\faBook]{article} % throws an error
%\pubtitle[\faBook]{custom} % throws an error

\section{Interface \texttt{\protect\string\Pubtitle}}
\showtest{\Pubtitle{book}}
\showtest{\Pubtitle{ArTiClE}}
\showtest{\Pubtitle[Beer,\faBeer]{custom}} % thanks Ulrich for the beer
\showtest{\Pubtitle[\faBeer]{custom}}
\showtest{\Pubtitle[Beer]{custom}}

%\Pubtitle{invalidArgument} % throws an error
%\Pubtitle[\faBook]{article} % throws an error
%\Pubtitle[\faBook]{custom} % throws an error
%\Pubtitle[\faBeer,Beer, and more]{custom} % throws an error
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I was just wondering if it is possible to set a default value for the symbol of ``pubtitle{custom}``?

Comment: @Vebjorn sure, it would, but I guess you'd require a title in that case (or do you want to default to `Custom`?), and in that case you'd have to somehow skip an optional argument, since currently the symbol comes first. All that is manageable, but please specify which behaviour exactly you'd like if `\pubtitle{custom}` and `\pubtitle[<one optional argument>]{custom}` is used.

Comment: I would like ``\pubtitle{custom}``  to produce ``\faFileTextO`` and ``Publications``. ``\pubtitle[title]{custom}`` should produce ``\faFileTextO`` and ``title``. And ``\pubtitle[Beer][\faBeer]{custom}`` should produce ``\faBeer`` and ``Beer``. Would also be nice if ``\pubtitle[\faBeer]{custom}`` produces ``\faBeer`` and ``Publications`` (but the last one is not as important).

Comment: @Vebjorn  1)  What shall happen in case optional arguments are provided while the mandatory argument does not equal the phrase "custom"?  2)  Consecutive optional arguments with no mandatory arguments between them is only a good idea with scenarios where optional arguments further back shall only be specified in cases where optional arguments further in front are specified also.

Comment: @Vebjorn see my edit that should implement what you want. But pay attention to what Ulrich wrote, that's very correct, consecutive optional arguments are often a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a command `\pubtitle` which usually processes only one mandatory argument but processes three mandatory arguments in case the first argument equals "custom", in which case the second mandatory argument is to denote the fontawesome-symbol and the third argument is to denote the text-phrase:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\definecolor{icons}{HTML}{46A247}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \pubtitle_symbolheading:nn
 {
  \group_begin:
  {\large\textcolor{icons}{#1}\hspace{10pt}\textbf{#2}}
  \group_end:
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\pubtitle}{m}
 {
  \pubtitle_pubtitle:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \pubtitle_pubtitle:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {book}{\pubtitle_symbolheading:nn{\faBook}{Book}}
    {article}{\pubtitle_symbolheading:nn{\faFileText}{Article}}
    % other cases
    % ...
    {custom}{\pubtitle_symbolheading:nn}% In cae of "custom" don't provide \pubtitle_symbolheading:nn's
                                        % arguments but let the user do it.
   }
   {% none of the above
    \PackageError{pubtitle}
     {
      Unsupported ~ entry ~ field ~ '#1' ~ \MessageBreak for bibliography}
     {
      Perhaps ~ you ~ meant ~ '\string\pubtitle{custom}'
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\pubtitle{book}

\pubtitle{article}

\pubtitle{custom}{\faBeer}{Beer!}

%\pubtitle{invalidArgument}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

Alternatively I can offer a variant of `\pubtitle` where syntax usually is
`\pubtitle{⟨mandatory⟩}`
, but in case *⟨mandatory⟩* holds the phrase "custom" syntax is
`\pubtitle[⟨symbol⟩]{custom}[⟨text-phrase⟩]`.

In the latter case

- the default for *⟨symbol⟩* is `\faFileTextO`.
- the default for *⟨text-phrase⟩* is `Publication`.

In the further case specifying optional arguments yields a warning-message that they are ignored.

This way you have two optional arguments separated by a mandatory argument and thus can easily specify symbol/text-phrase separately without the need of having your macros parse the optional argument for detecting what the user might have provided.

The gist is:

First it is checked whether the mandatory argument equals "custom".
Then in both cases presence of optional arguments is checked.

In case the mandatory argument equals the phrase "custom" only optional arguments actually provided by the user are passed on to a macro
which processes optional arguments which have default-values and does `\pubtitle_symbolheading:nn`.

In case the mandatory argument does not equal the phrase "custom" presence of optional arguments leads to warning-messages about optional-arguments being ignored.
Then `\pubtitle_pubtitle:n` is carried out for forking the different non-"custom" cases for the mandatory argument.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\definecolor{icons}{HTML}{46A247}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \pubtitle_symbolheading:nn
 {
  \group_begin:
  {\large\textcolor{icons}{#1}\hspace{10pt}\textbf{#2}}
  \group_end:
 }
\cs_new:Nn \pubtitle_optional_args_present_fork:nnnnnn 
  {
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#3}{#4}}
                    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#5}{#6}}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\pubtitle}{omo}
  {
    \str_case:nnF { #2 }
     {
        {custom}{
                  \pubtitle_optional_args_present_fork:nnnnnn{#1}{#3}
                  {\pubtitle_custom{}}
                  {\pubtitle_custom{}[{#3}]}
                  {\pubtitle_custom[{#1}]{}}
                  {\pubtitle_custom[{#1}]{}[{#3}]}
                }
     }
     {
        \pubtitle_optional_args_present_fork:nnnnnn{#1}{#3}
           {}
           {\pubtitle_superfluous_opt_args_warning{\pubtitle}{[#3]}}
           {\pubtitle_superfluous_opt_args_warning{\pubtitle}{[#1]}}
           {\pubtitle_superfluous_opt_args_warning{\pubtitle}{[#1]/[#3]}}
        \pubtitle_pubtitle:n{#2}
     }
   }
\NewDocumentCommand{\pubtitle_custom}{O{\faFileTextO}mO{Publication}}
  {
    \pubtitle_symbolheading:nn{#1}{#3}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \pubtitle_pubtitle:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {book}{\pubtitle_symbolheading:nn{\faBook}{Book}}
    {article}{\pubtitle_symbolheading:nn{\faFileText}{Article}}
    %
    % other non-custom-cases
    %
   }
   {\pubtitle_unsupported_entry_field_error{\pubtitle}{#1} }
 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_msg_module_type_prop { pubtitle } {}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_msg_module_name_prop { pubtitle } {Macro-Defined-In-Preamble:}
\msg_new:nnnn {pubtitle} 
              {superfluous optional arguments}
              {Macro~#1:~Ignoring~superfluous~optional~argument(s)~#2~as~it~is/they~are~provided~while~not~doing~a~"custom"-thingie~\msg_line_context: .}
              {With~macro~#1~specifying~optional~arguments~only~makes~sense~if~the~mandatory~argument~equals~"custom".}
\cs_new:Npn \pubtitle_superfluous_opt_args_warning #1 #2 {
  \exp_args:Nne \use:n  {
    \msg_warning:nnnn {pubtitle} {superfluous optional arguments}
  }{\iow_char:N \\\cs_to_str:N #1}{#2}
}
\msg_new:nnnn {pubtitle} 
              {unsupported entry field}
              {Macro~#1:~Unsupported~ entry~field~'#2'~for~bibliography~\msg_line_context: .}
              {Perhaps~you~meant~'#1\pubtitle{custom}'.}
\cs_new:Npn \pubtitle_unsupported_entry_field_error #1 #2 {
  \exp_args:Nne \use:n  {
    \msg_error:nnnn {pubtitle} {unsupported entry field}
  }{\iow_char:N \\\cs_to_str:N #1}{#2}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent\verb|\pubtitle{book}|\\
\pubtitle{book}

\medskip

\noindent\verb|\pubtitle{article}|\\
\noindent\pubtitle{article}

\medskip

\noindent\verb|\pubtitle{custom}|\\
\pubtitle{custom}

\medskip

\noindent\verb|\pubtitle[\faBeer]{custom}|\\
\pubtitle[\faBeer]{custom}


\medskip

\noindent\verb|\pubtitle{custom}[Beer!]|\\
\pubtitle{custom}[Beer!]


\medskip

\noindent\verb|\pubtitle[\faBeer]{custom}[Beer!]|\\
\pubtitle[\faBeer]{custom}[Beer!]

% Switch to \iftrue to see warning-messages in case optional arguments are provided with non-custom-thingie:

\iffalse
%\iftrue

\medskip

\noindent\verb|\pubtitle[\faBeer]{book}|\\
\pubtitle[\faBeer]{book}

\medskip

\noindent\verb|\pubtitle{book}[Beer!]|\\
\pubtitle{book}[Beer!]

\medskip

\noindent\verb|\pubtitle[\faBeer]{book}[Beer!]|\\
\pubtitle[\faBeer]{book}[Beer!]

\fi

% Switch to \iftrue to see error-messages in case an undefined-custom-thingie is provided as
% mandatory argument:

\iffalse
%\iftrue


\medskip

\noindent\verb|\pubtitle{invalidArgument}|\\
\pubtitle{invalidArgument}

\medskip

\noindent\verb|\pubtitle[\faBeer]{invalidArgument}|\\
\pubtitle[\faBeer]{invalidArgument}

\medskip

\noindent\verb|\pubtitle{invalidArgument}[Beer!]|\\
\pubtitle{invalidArgument}[Beer!]

\medskip

\noindent\verb|\pubtitle[\faBeer]{invalidArgument}[Beer!]|\\
\pubtitle[\faBeer]{invalidArgument}[Beer!]

\fi

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

You can use a key-val-system like l3keys of expl3 and have one key—let's call it "symbol"—for the fontawesome-symbol and another key—let's call it "text"—for the text-phrase and define meta-keys "book"/"article" which in turn provide predefined key-val-lists of pattern `symbol=..., text=...`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\definecolor{icons}{HTML}{46A247}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \__pubtitle_symbol: {}
\cs_new:Npn \__pubtitle_text: {}
\keys_define:nn { pubtitle }
{
   symbol.cs_set:Np = \__pubtitle_symbol: ,
   symbol.value_required:n = true ,
   symbol.initial:n = \q_no_value ,
   text.cs_set:Np = \__pubtitle_text: ,
   text.value_required:n = true ,
   text.initial:n = \q_no_value ,
   %% meta-keys denoting presets of symbol=..., text=...
   book.meta:n = {symbol=\faBook, text=Book,}, book.value_forbidden:n = true,
   article.meta:n = {symbol=\faFileText, text=Article,}, article.value_forbidden:n = true,
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pubtitle #1 
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { pubtitle } { #1 } 
  \exp_args:No \quark_if_no_value:nTF {\__pubtitle_symbol:}{
      \pubtitle_missing_value_error{\pubtitle}{symbol}
      \exp_args:No \quark_if_no_value:nT {\__pubtitle_text:}{
          \pubtitle_missing_value_error{\pubtitle}{text}
      }
  }{
      \exp_args:No \quark_if_no_value:nTF {\__pubtitle_text:}{
          \pubtitle_missing_value_error{\pubtitle}{text}
      }{
          {\large\textcolor{icons}{\__pubtitle_symbol:}\hspace{10pt}\textbf{\__pubtitle_text:}}
      }
  }
  \group_end:
 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_msg_module_type_prop { pubtitle } {}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_msg_module_name_prop { pubtitle } {Macro-Defined-In-Preamble:}
\msg_new:nnnn {pubtitle} 
              {missing value}
              {Macro~#1:~No~value~for~key~'#2'~provided~\msg_line_context: .}
              {Provide~a~value~for~key~'#2'!}
\cs_new:Npn \pubtitle_missing_value_error #1 #2 {
  % \msg_error:... etc turn their arguments into strings, but let's make sure
  % the control-sequence whose name is to be displayed is stringified with a
  % leading backslash regardless the current value of the \escapechar parameter:
  \exp_args:Nne \use:n  {
    \msg_error:nnnn {pubtitle} {missing value}
  }{\iow_char:N \\\cs_to_str:N #1}{#2}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent\verb|\pubtitle{book}|:\\
\pubtitle{book}

\medskip

\noindent\verb|\pubtitle{article}|:\\
\pubtitle{article}

\medskip

\noindent Customizing by providing keys \verb|symbol|/\verb|text| additionally to or instead
of meta-keys like \verb|book|/\verb|article|:

\medskip

\noindent\verb|\pubtitle{symbol=\faBeer, text=Beer!}|:\\
\pubtitle{symbol=\faBeer, text=Beer!}

\medskip

\noindent\verb|\pubtitle{book, text=Beer!}|:\\
\pubtitle{book, text=Beer!}

\medskip

\noindent\verb|\pubtitle{book, symbol=\faBeer}|:\\
\pubtitle{book, symbol=\faBeer}

% Test error-messages:
%\pubtitle{invalidArgument}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd discourage the varying number of mandatory arguments, but `Beer!` sounds like a good idea :)

Comment: What I forgot to write: But +1 for the key=val solution :)